# Tree component in JSF

Tags: java, jsf

What is a good tree component in JSF. I also want the user to be able to select one (using radiobutton) or more than one node (using checkboxes) from that tree component. Is there any existing component that meets my need?

thanks
Vikas

Answer (score 3):

I've used many of the rich faces components and they all work very well. Easy to implement as well.  Have a look at http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/tree.jsf

Answer (score 1):

Just search for your component from the component based frameworks available [here](http://www.jsfmatrix.net/). I have seen tree components developed by ICEFaces. Not sure whether it specifically addresses your needs of using radio/checkbox with tree. Neverthless the demo url available in the above link will help you decide.

Note: I havent used these frameowrks to write production code. So you also need to check for performace issues related to each of these frameworks before choosing one.

Answer (score 1):

Look to my blog http://blog.jvsystem.pl - richfaces tree component - there is simple tutorial how to create tree in richfaces.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [myFaces](http://www.irian.at/myfacesexamples/tree.jsf) Tree component if you are using this library in your application.
Other option is [rich faces](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/tree.jsf) tree.

There might be more if you google for better and suitable option for your need.